# Stm32F746g ADC SCAN mode not printing any values through DMA

Tags: stm32, adc, dma, stmcubeide

I have an STM32F746g-Disco board that I'm using to continuously read 4 ADC channels directly to the memory. I've tested the ADC on continuous conversion mode for each pin separately and it works, but as soon as I enable scan mode and DMA, nothing gets read into my `adcValues` array.

I was initially using ADC_SOFTWARE_START for the external conversion trigger, but [someone over in the ST forum](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-embedded-software/help-with-stm32f746g-adc-scan-mode-dma/td-p/590942) said that it is only a software parameter used for compatibility with other STM32 devices. I'm not sure if that is correct or not, because I've seen some others online using this setting. At his suggestion, I implemented TIM1 to handle the conversion trigger, but I still can't get the ADC to read the values into the array.

I'm using HAL libraries set up by STMCubeIDE so at this point I'm wondering if it's a HAL Native problem that just hasn't been identified. That said, it seems far more likely that I've just made an initialization mistake.

I've attached the code to my `main.c` file in the code section. Could someone more knowledgeable than me take a look at it and see if I'm setting anything up incorrectly? Thank you!

Edit: Here's some more info. The HCLK is at 200 MHz. The ADC is hooked up to the Arduino style headers, where I'm using potentiometers to feed in values. The `while` loop of the program will be time sensitive and fairly computationally involved, so I'm hoping to have the ADC run in the background instead of having to ask it to read constantly in the while loop.

```c
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc3;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc3;

CRC_HandleTypeDef hcrc;

DMA2D_HandleTypeDef hdma2d;

LTDC_HandleTypeDef hltdc;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim4;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart4;

SDRAM_HandleTypeDef hsdram1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM4_Init(void);
static void MX_LTDC_Init(void);
static void MX_UART4_Init(void);
static void MX_CRC_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA2D_Init(void);
static void MX_FMC_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC3_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
float rotationmain;
float rotationfactor;
float mixfactormain;
int countermain;
uint32_t adcValues[4] = {0};  // To store ADC values of channels 0-3
float32_t* renderedModel;

TS_StateTypeDef  ts;

char xTouchStr[10];

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    /* Enable the CPU Cache */
    /* Enable I-Cache */
    SCB_EnableICache();
    /* Enable D-Cache */
    SCB_EnableDCache();
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
  BSP_SDRAM_Init(); /* Initializes the SDRAM device */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_TIM4_Init();
  MX_LTDC_Init();
  MX_UART4_Init();
  MX_CRC_Init();
  MX_DMA2D_Init();
  MX_FMC_Init();
  MX_ADC3_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  BSP_TS_Init(480, 272);
    __HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_ENABLE();


  dsp3D_init();

  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc3, (uint32_t*)adcValues, 4);

  SwitchState currentState = SWITCH_STATE_INVALID;
  SwitchState previousState = SWITCH_STATE_INVALID;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }

  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 12;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 192;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Activate the Over-Drive mode
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC3_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC3_Init 1 */


  /* USER CODE END ADC3_Init 1 */

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc3.Instance = ADC3;
  hadc3.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc3.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc3.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc3.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc3.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc3.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc3.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T1_CC1;
  hadc3.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc3.Init.NbrOfConversion = 4;
  hadc3.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc3.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_7;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_3;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_4;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC3_Init 2 */


  /* USER CODE END ADC3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief CRC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_CRC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CRC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CRC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CRC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CRC_Init 1 */
  hcrc.Instance = CRC;
  hcrc.Init.DefaultPolynomialUse = DEFAULT_POLYNOMIAL_ENABLE;
  hcrc.Init.DefaultInitValueUse = DEFAULT_INIT_VALUE_ENABLE;
  hcrc.Init.InputDataInversionMode = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_NONE;
  hcrc.Init.OutputDataInversionMode = CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_DISABLE;
  hcrc.InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES;
  if (HAL_CRC_Init(&hcrc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CRC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END CRC_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief DMA2D Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_DMA2D_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2D_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2D_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2D_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2D_Init 1 */
  hdma2d.Instance = DMA2D;
  hdma2d.Init.Mode = DMA2D_M2M;
  hdma2d.Init.ColorMode = DMA2D_OUTPUT_ARGB8888;
  hdma2d.Init.OutputOffset = 0;
  hdma2d.LayerCfg[1].InputOffset = 0;
  hdma2d.LayerCfg[1].InputColorMode = DMA2D_INPUT_ARGB8888;
  hdma2d.LayerCfg[1].AlphaMode = DMA2D_NO_MODIF_ALPHA;
  hdma2d.LayerCfg[1].InputAlpha = 0;
  if (HAL_DMA2D_Init(&hdma2d) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_DMA2D_ConfigLayer(&hdma2d, 1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2D_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2D_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief LTDC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_LTDC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LTDC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END LTDC_Init 0 */

  LTDC_LayerCfgTypeDef pLayerCfg = {0};
  LTDC_LayerCfgTypeDef pLayerCfg1 = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LTDC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END LTDC_Init 1 */
  hltdc.Instance = LTDC;
  hltdc.Init.HSPolarity = LTDC_HSPOLARITY_AL;
  hltdc.Init.VSPolarity = LTDC_VSPOLARITY_AL;
  hltdc.Init.DEPolarity = LTDC_DEPOLARITY_AL;
  hltdc.Init.PCPolarity = LTDC_PCPOLARITY_IPC;
  hltdc.Init.HorizontalSync = 7;
  hltdc.Init.VerticalSync = 3;
  hltdc.Init.AccumulatedHBP = 14;
  hltdc.Init.AccumulatedVBP = 5;
  hltdc.Init.AccumulatedActiveW = 654;
  hltdc.Init.AccumulatedActiveH = 485;
  hltdc.Init.TotalWidth = 660;
  hltdc.Init.TotalHeigh = 487;
  hltdc.Init.Backcolor.Blue = 0;
  hltdc.Init.Backcolor.Green = 0;
  hltdc.Init.Backcolor.Red = 0;
  if (HAL_LTDC_Init(&hltdc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  pLayerCfg.WindowX0 = 0;
  pLayerCfg.WindowX1 = 0;
  pLayerCfg.WindowY0 = 0;
  pLayerCfg.WindowY1 = 0;
  pLayerCfg.PixelFormat = LTDC_PIXEL_FORMAT_ARGB8888;
  pLayerCfg.Alpha = 0;
  pLayerCfg.Alpha0 = 0;
  pLayerCfg.BlendingFactor1 = LTDC_BLENDING_FACTOR1_CA;
  pLayerCfg.BlendingFactor2 = LTDC_BLENDING_FACTOR2_CA;
  pLayerCfg.FBStartAdress = 0;
  pLayerCfg.ImageWidth = 0;
  pLayerCfg.ImageHeight = 0;
  pLayerCfg.Backcolor.Blue = 0;
  pLayerCfg.Backcolor.Green = 0;
  pLayerCfg.Backcolor.Red = 0;
  if (HAL_LTDC_ConfigLayer(&hltdc, &pLayerCfg, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  pLayerCfg1.WindowX0 = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.WindowX1 = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.WindowY0 = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.WindowY1 = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.PixelFormat = LTDC_PIXEL_FORMAT_ARGB8888;
  pLayerCfg1.Alpha = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.Alpha0 = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.BlendingFactor1 = LTDC_BLENDING_FACTOR1_CA;
  pLayerCfg1.BlendingFactor2 = LTDC_BLENDING_FACTOR2_CA;
  pLayerCfg1.FBStartAdress = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.ImageWidth = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.ImageHeight = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.Backcolor.Blue = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.Backcolor.Green = 0;
  pLayerCfg1.Backcolor.Red = 0;
  if (HAL_LTDC_ConfigLayer(&hltdc, &pLayerCfg1, 1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN LTDC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END LTDC_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 576;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 1000;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  __HAL_TIM_ENABLE_OCxPRELOAD(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2State = TIM_BREAK2_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Polarity = TIM_BREAK2POLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Filter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM4 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM4_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 1 */
  htim4.Instance = TIM4;
  htim4.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim4.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim4.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim4.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim4.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim4, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim4, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief UART4 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_UART4_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN UART4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END UART4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN UART4_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END UART4_Init 1 */
  huart4.Instance = UART4;
  huart4.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart4.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart4.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart4.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart4.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart4.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart4.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart4.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart4.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN UART4_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END UART4_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream0_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn);

}

/* FMC initialization function */
static void MX_FMC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FMC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END FMC_Init 0 */

  FMC_SDRAM_TimingTypeDef SdramTiming = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FMC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END FMC_Init 1 */

  /** Perform the SDRAM1 memory initialization sequence
  */
  hsdram1.Instance = FMC_SDRAM_DEVICE;
  /* hsdram1.Init */
  hsdram1.Init.SDBank = FMC_SDRAM_BANK1;
  hsdram1.Init.ColumnBitsNumber = FMC_SDRAM_COLUMN_BITS_NUM_9;
  hsdram1.Init.RowBitsNumber = FMC_SDRAM_ROW_BITS_NUM_12;
  hsdram1.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FMC_SDRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16;
  hsdram1.Init.InternalBankNumber = FMC_SDRAM_INTERN_BANKS_NUM_4;
  hsdram1.Init.CASLatency = FMC_SDRAM_CAS_LATENCY_1;
  hsdram1.Init.WriteProtection = FMC_SDRAM_WRITE_PROTECTION_DISABLE;
  hsdram1.Init.SDClockPeriod = FMC_SDRAM_CLOCK_DISABLE;
  hsdram1.Init.ReadBurst = FMC_SDRAM_RBURST_DISABLE;
  hsdram1.Init.ReadPipeDelay = FMC_SDRAM_RPIPE_DELAY_0;
  /* SdramTiming */
  SdramTiming.LoadToActiveDelay = 16;
  SdramTiming.ExitSelfRefreshDelay = 16;
  SdramTiming.SelfRefreshTime = 16;
  SdramTiming.RowCycleDelay = 16;
  SdramTiming.WriteRecoveryTime = 16;
  SdramTiming.RPDelay = 16;
  SdramTiming.RCDDelay = 16;

  if (HAL_SDRAM_Init(&hsdram1, &SdramTiming) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler( );
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FMC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END FMC_Init 2 */
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOJ_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOK_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOI_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : A0_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = A0_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(A0_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */


SwitchState getSwitchState(uint32_t adcValue) {
    if (adcValue <= 1023) {
        return SWITCH_STATE_1;
    } else if (adcValue <= 2047) {
        return SWITCH_STATE_2;
    } else if (adcValue <= 3071) {
        return SWITCH_STATE_3;
    } else if (adcValue <= 4095) {
        return SWITCH_STATE_4;
    } else {
        return SWITCH_STATE_INVALID;
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```